# How to remove sender name before `@` in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $str = "xyz@gmail.com";
    $username = strstr($str, '@', true);
    echo $username;
?>
```

I want to remove sender name before `@` tag and output should be `@gmail.com`. Now,  It shows me `xyz` output which I don't want. So, How can I do this? Please help me.
I want to output `@gmail.com`.

Comment: Just remove the `true` parameter to [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) and it will give you the text *after* (and including) the delimiter

Comment: This is also fun, but not worthy of an answer: `strrev(strtok(strrev('xyz@gmail.com'), '@'));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$str = "xyz@gmail.com";

$tld = explode("@", $str)[1]; // gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the part before the @-character with an empty string:

```
$username = preg_replace('/^[^@]+/', '', $str);
```